# Oracle Perfomance - JDBC Oracle Thin driver: Use parameters or not?

Tags: performance, oracle, jdbc

I have two decades SQL experience, but not specifically with Oracle. An 'Oracle expert' assures me that building a SQL query without parameters (like this):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Address ... FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ID = 'someID' AND t.Name = 'someName'...
```

is at least as fast as using parameters (like this)

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, t.Address ... FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ID = ? AND t.Name = ?
```

The code is executed in a loop.

In most other databases I have experience with, using parameters increases speed. It allows the database to cache the compiled plan that matches the SQL statement. Since the SQL does not change per invocation (although the parameters do) this improves performance. The database simply binds the parameters and continues.

The 'Oracle expert' states that this is not necessary. But obviously, Oracle needs to 'parse out' the parameters, match the remaining string to a cached execution plan, then rebind the parameters as if they were passed along as parameters in the first place.

Do I have the correct mental picture here? Is there something 'magical' about Oracle that it really does not make a difference how we approach our parameter passing/SQL building strategy?

Are there thoughts about Java / JDBC / Oracle thin driver that I am not aware of that I should be aware of here?

I am looking to either reinforce my understanding or to expand my knowledge.

(Security concerns aside please, I understand that building SQL strings allows for SQL injection attacks, I am looking for more direct ammunition to use against the experts opinion - if it exists).

Other details: `Oracle 11gR2, Java 1.6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be blunt - you got it right, and your Oracle expert seems to be no expert at all (unless he wants to sell expensive consulting time for speeding up your application once you've put it into production).

If you build the SQL statement without parameters (called bind variables in Oracle), you force the database to hard parse the statement every time it is executed.

See [AskTom on soft/hard parsing and bind variables](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2588723819082) for a much better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Using parameters is almost always preferable. If you use literals (version one), thousands of slightly different SQL-Statements will hit the database, causing a hard parse and filling up Oracle's statement cache.

Here is the one exception to the rule: If you are querying a column that has a very uneven distribution of values, the version with the literal might allow the query optimizer to find a better plan.

For example, assuming that an overwhelming majority of slashdot readers is male(*),

```
select * from slashdot_readers where gender='MALE';
```

might cause the query optimizer to ignore an index on `gender` and do a full table scan instead, while

```
select * from slashdot_readers where gender='FEMALE';
```

might cause it to use the index. With a variable, the query optimizer will not know which version to use, so it might always do the full table scan.

(*) just for the sake of this example

Answer (score 1):

I have not done any performance measurements, but I think that your picture is right. In any case, even if they would be equally fast, I would always prefer the variant using parameters / bind variables to prevent from SQL injection. That might not be an issue in your sample where you have fixed strings in your where clause, but in real applications these strings usually come from somewhere outside. (I think you edited your question when I just wrote this answer :-) )

Comment: ;) - for me the SQL Injection is enough of a reason. Thank you for helping me build the case.

Answer (score 1):

Do some measurement. Get data.

From everything I know about Oracle - you should be right. Obviously make sure if it's in a loop you're re-executing the same `PreparedStatement` and not re-preparing it each time. That alone may reduce the cost of the query.

One thing to watch out for - your real application may benefit even *more* from bind variables than a simple test case, because in the real application Oracle will have all kinds of other SQL statements in its cache (I forget the terminology for the different memory areas and caches in Oracle at the moment) and as that fills up, the cost of sending in new SQL all the time goes up quite a bit.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the hard parsed strings are crowding out other cached statements from the cache.