# How to DISTINCT in Hibernate with Blob in Table?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, blob, distinct

I've got a problem with my Query.
Theres a table "TEAM" with a Row "PHOTO" from Type BLOB

My Query looks like:

```
  select distinct gruppe 
  from Gruppe gruppe 
     left outer join fetch gruppe.teams teams 
     inner join teams.turniere as turnier 
   where turnier.id = " + this.getTurnierId() + " order by gruppe.gruppenIndex"
```

the problem is that oracle returns an error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

I've figured out that oracle is not able to use a distinct while there is a BLOB inside a table.. Any suggestions? :-)

Regards,
Kev

Comment: Why would you want to do a `distinct` on all columns of a table? Apart from the obvious problem with the `BLOB` datatype it doesn't make sense as that will also include the PK of the table and therefor the `distinct` will not remove any rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that a single turniere can be shared between many teams.

```
select gruppe
from Gruppe gruppe
where gruppe.id in (
    select distinct gruppe.id
    from Gruppe gruppe 
    left outer join fetch gruppe.teams teams 
    inner join teams.turniere as turnier 
    where turnier.id = :id
) order by gruppe.gruppenIndex
```

P.S. Indexed or named parameters will have better performance with Oracle than values hardcoded in the query string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896752/oracle-perfomance-jdbc-oracle-thin-driver-use-parameters-or-not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a SQL query to get it fixed .
Basically we can write SQL Quires in Hibernate..